# linq to json target specific items to deserialize

Tags: c#, json, linq

So here's my code:

```
        // converts JSON data to an object I can use to pull select data out of
        JObject o = JObject.Parse(data);

        // this works fine. I can go one layer deep for a single piece of data
        int count = (int)o["count"];
        Console.WriteLine("This: {0} should say 30", count);

        // this also works. I can go multiple layers deep for SINGLE pieces of data...
        string publisherOne = (string)o["recipes"][0]["publisher"];
        Console.WriteLine("This: {0} should say Closet Cooking", publisherOne);

        // this is where the issue is... I can't go multiple layers deep and
        // get single pieces of data from each JSON object
        List<string> allPublishers = o["recipes"]["publisher"].Select(t => (string)t).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(allPublishers[2] + "should say picky palate");
```

data is a string of JSON, which here is a sample of what I'm using: (It's longer, but this is enough)

```
{
  "count": 30,
  "recipes": [
{
  "publisher": "Closet Cooking",
  "f2f_url": "http://food2fork.com/view/35186",
  "title": "Caprese Grilled Cheese Sandwich",
  "source_url": "http://www.closetcooking.com/2011/09/caprese-grilled-cheese-sandwich.html",
  "recipe_id": "35186",
  "image_url": "http://static.food2fork.com/Caprese2BGrilled2BCheese2BSandwich2B5002B21616ce448f5.jpg",
  "social_rank": 99.99999999999993,
  "publisher_url": "http://closetcooking.com"
},
{
  "publisher": "Closet Cooking",
  "f2f_url": "http://food2fork.com/view/35596",
  "title": "Spinach Pesto Grilled Cheese Sandwich",
  "source_url": "http://www.closetcooking.com/2010/05/spinach-pesto-grilled-cheese-sandwich.html",
  "recipe_id": "35596",
  "image_url": "http://static.food2fork.com/SpinachPestoGrilledCheeseSandwich50053b8a9a0.jpg",
  "social_rank": 99.99999999999862,
  "publisher_url": "http://closetcooking.com"
},
{
  "publisher": "Picky Palate",
  "f2f_url": "http://food2fork.com/view/484d98",
  "title": "Crock Pot Pesto Ranch Chicken Thighs",
  "source_url": "http://picky-palate.com/2012/09/20/pesto-ranch-crock-pot-chicken-thighs/",
  "recipe_id": "484d98",
  "image_url": "http://static.food2fork.com/CrockPotPestoRanchChickenThighs1text1300x248ca0b.jpg",
  "social_rank": 99.99999999941502,
  "publisher_url": "http://picky-palate.com"
},
```

The first two (count and publisherOne) work absolutely fine.
allPublishers is supposed to be a list of all the publishers, but it's causing me trouble because the publisher info is just a single piece of data within the array of recipes. This is what I'm using for reference in trying to do this:
http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use these classes

```
public class Recipe
{
    public string publisher { get; set; }
    public string f2f_url { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string source_url { get; set; }
    public string recipe_id { get; set; }
    public string image_url { get; set; }
    public double social_rank { get; set; }
    public string publisher_url { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int count { get; set; }
    public List<Recipe> recipes { get; set; }
}
```

and

deserialize as

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json)
```

Now you can write your linq in a *compile-time safe* way

*PS: See http://json2csharp.com/*

Comment: oh sorry... I should probably be more specific. I used something similar to your code and it worked, but the data I'm using now is actually layered a lot more and I was just using this data set to test if I could do what I described above. Is the problem how I'm approaching this though and unnecessarily creating a problem?

Comment: @ConnorJensen I am not sure I can understand your problem, but it is not import how deep your nested classes are, Just create your classes using that site and write your linq.

Comment: yup that's what I'm doing now... thank you for referencing me to that tool, I think that solves my problems :)